# Como desenvolver programas para Android através do Python?

Tags: android, python

Para desenvolver programas para Android no Python é necessário construir um framework de tal forma que o aplicativo seja executável em celulares Android?

Eu sou novo como programador Android, estou estudando e soube que o Python tem uma grande portabilidade. Como posso escrever programas para Android em Python? É possível?

Comment: Talvez fuja do assunto, mas caso você tenha conhecimentos de C# e prefira ele do que Java recomendo a você dar uma olhada no **Xamarin**. [Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com)

Answer (score 7):

Você pode dar uma olhada no framework `Kivy`, ele é open source, desenvolvido em `Python` para programar em `Python`, focada em aplicações modernas, sendo multiplataforma, multitoque, de código aberto, simples e veloz.

Sobre a instalação  e requisitos você pode dar uma olhada na resposta a esta pergunta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353481/how-good-is-kivy-for-android), não vou me aventurar a traduzir a resposta, pois meu inglês ainda é pobre.

Para mais sobre o kivy você pode consultar a [Documentação](http://kivy.org/docs/) ou o projeto no [GitHub](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android), há também essa palestra no [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdXLnFZ3eQQ) sobre o desenvolvimento de apps com o `Kivy`.

Nota: Nunca fiz a instalação ou testes com o `Kivy` apenas li sobre ele em alguns posts na comunidade `Python`, então não poderei dar informações mais detalhadas sobre o `Kivy`.

Comment: Olá Snickers. As informações que você postou estão muito genéricas, e assim a resposta fica praticamente dependente dos links. Se você não conhece a ferramenta, talvez seja melhor indicá-la em um comentário. Ou você pode tentar dar uma visão geral de seu uso, postar um exemplo, ou até mesmo "traduzir" a resposta do SOen que você referenciou (entre outras opções), tornando assim a sua resposta potencialmente mais útil para a comunidade. :)

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra alternativa é o [`QPython`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hipipal.qpyplus&hl=pt_BR) que permite criar e executar *scripts* no Android, ele vem com um kit de desenvolvimento que contem:

- **Console**: Um console para Python regular, sinta-se livre para se comunicar com interpretador diretamente.
- **Editor**: QPython tem um bom editor de texto integrado, você pode escrever o código e executá-lo sem sair do aplicativo.
- **My QPython**: Aqui você pode encontrar seus *scripts* e projetos.
- **System**: Manutenção de bibliotecas e componentes, instalar e desinstalar-los.
- **Package Index**: Abre a página [QPyPI](http://packages.qpython.org/) no navegador que permite instalar pacotes listados lá.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um *Hello World* em QPython:

```
import androidhelper

ah = androidhelper.Android()
response = ah.dialogGetInput("Hello", "Enter your name:")
message = 'Hello, %s!' % response.result
ah.makeToast(message)
```

Você pode encontrar mais informações na [wiki do QPython](http://wiki.qpython.org/). Na página [**Mobile Device Editors**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors#Mobile_Device_Editors) dispõe uma lista de *IDE's* que são executados em dispositivos móveis e *tablets*.

Comment: Você saberia dizer (sem precisar entrar muito em detalhes) se é possível criar aplicativos "standalone" usando esse kit? Tipo, você desenvolve e publica numa app store, sem precisar do usuário final baixar o QPython, baixar seu código e executar manualmente. Se ele está limitado a scripts (como me parece ser o caso, não encontrei nenhuma opção de *deploy*), isso reduz muito sua utilidade... (além do que, não me sinto confortável instalando um aplicativo que execute código arbitrário - principalmente se ele precisa que eu lhe dê permissões bastante abrangentes)

Comment: Também seria interessante colocar algum exemplo de código, de uso ou de integração com o kit, pra que a resposta fique mais interessante e útil. Do jeito que está, me parece mais um comentário do que propriamente uma resposta.